# Anybody help me execute command in java

Tags: java, windows, cmd

When execute batch file through java web application, there is something wrong as below description.

I don't know why only case 1 works as expected, in case2,3,4 only a part of batch file is executed. Anyone can explain to me why? Thank a lot.

Execute command using `Runtime.getruntime().exec(command)`

```
case1. cmd /c start C:\mytest.bat
case2. cmd /c start /b C:\mytest.bat
case3. cmd /c C:\mytest.bat
case4. C:\mytest.bat
```

**mytest.bat**

```
echo line1 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line2 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line3 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line4 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line5 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line6 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line7 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line8 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line9 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line10 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line11 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line12 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line13 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line14 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line15 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line16 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line17 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line18 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line19 >>%~dp0test.txt
echo line20 >>%~dp0test.txt
exit
```

**Result test.txt**

Case1:

```
line1 
line2 
line3 
line4 
line5 
line6 
line7 
line8 
line9 
line10 
line11 
line12 
line13 
line14 
line15 
line16 
line17 
line18 
line19 
line20
```

Cases 2,3,4:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this happens because your program terminates before the underlying Process (the execution of `mytext.bat`) is done. in your first case you use `start` which starts the execution in its own environment, so the execution continues even when its parent terminates. All of your other commands execute the Batch file in the current environment and terminate with you application.

To fix this you have to wait for the execution of `mytext.bat` to finish. there are several ways to do this, but i would recommend using a Process Builder:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "C:\\mytest.bat");
Process p = b.start();
p.waitFor();
```

To use your approach:

```
Process p = Runtime.getruntime().exec(command)
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: You should notice that `p.waitFor()` can throw an `InterruptedException` that should then be handled.

Answer (score 0):

just add /wait to your commands starting by the second command like this :

```
 cmd /c start C:\mytest.bat
 case2. cmd /c start /wait /b C:\mytest.bat
 case3. cmd /c /wait C:\mytest.bat
 case4. C:\mytest.bat
```

Answer (score -1):

When you execute a command without opening a window with /b option or without start, you need to keep a pause. Here I kept a pause of one second and the program is perfectly working.

```
public class MyTest{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start D:\\mytest.bat");//No pause required
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /b D:\\mytest.bat");//pause required
        //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c D:\\mytest.bat");//pause required
        //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\mytest.bat");//pause required
        Thread.sleep(1000);//Pause for one second
    }
}
```

Comment: A pause of a second will only work if the command in question is terminated within that second. Any command taking more than that will suffer an unsuspected termination.

Comment: True but based on OP requirement, that suffices. `Process.waitFor()` was also not working.

Comment: `Process.waitFor()` should have been working. Why didn't it? (Did you check for correct termination?)